# How to get values from ForeignKey's related model in Django queryset?

Tags: django

I'm having trouble accessing a field in a related model using a foreign key.

I have two models, Person and Party as outlined below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 4, blank=True, null=True)
    first = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party, related_name = 'parties', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class Party(models.Model):

    party_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    party_code = models.CharField(max_length = 5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.party_name
```

I'm trying to get a count of people in each party.  I'd like the result to look like:

```
[{
    "party_name": "Democrat",
    "total_members": 93
},
{
    "party_name": "Republican",
    "total_members": 32
},
{
    "party_name": "Non-Partisan",
    "total_members": 34
}]
```

My serializer is as follows:

```
class CountPartiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    total_members = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'party', 'total_members')
```

And my viewset is as follows:

```
class CountPartiesViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.values('party__party_name').annotate(total_members = Count('id'))
    serializer_class = CountPartiesSerializer
```

But this results in the following:

```
[{
    "party": null,
    "total_members": 34
},
{
    "party": null,
    "total_members": 93
},
{
    "party": null,
    "total_members": 32
}]
```

I've tried a million different things and I know I'm missing something, but I can't figure out how to get this working.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're serializing the wrong thing. Your serializer should be based on Party, and you can then add the count of members.

**Edit**

```
class PartySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_members = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Party
        fields = ('name', 'total_members')


class PartyViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Party.objects.values('name').annotate(total_members=Count('parties'))
    serializer_class = PartySerializer
```

You do of course have a relation between party and person: it is the reverse relationship of your foreign key. Note, the name you have chosen for the related_name there is confusing; it should be 'people', or just leave it as the default, which would be 'person_set'.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you elaborate on how I would do that?  I'm not sure what my PartySerializer would look like in that case and/or how I would get a reference to the number of people (since the Party model isn't related back to the Person model if that makes any sense).

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked!  Still wrapping my head around relationships in Django.